# How can I download an ENCODE data set from the file name?

Tags: python, r, bash, unix, encode

I have a list of .narrowPeak ENCODE file names (eg. wgEncodeAwgTfbsSydhGm12878Chd2ab68301IggmusUniPk.narrowPeak). 
For a single file, it's easy enough to find the file address and wget; however, I have hundreds of such files and doing this for each file would be a slog. From the file names alone, is there a way to bulk download ENCODE data files using bash, R, or python?

First time working with ENCODE data, so apologies if this is simple.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the process. To me, with no knowledge about narrowPeak, it's not clear how wgetting a file you have comes in...

Comment: Yes, can you give more context about the source of the data and how you are pulling it down?

Comment: I don't have the file itself, just the file name. For example, [here's](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeAwgTfbsUniform/) a list of zipped ENCODE data sets. I can copy the link address for a given file and wget, but I'd prefer to automate the process and supply a list of the files I need.